# Hyperlinked text of QtGui.QTextEdit in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a QtGui.QTextEdit textDocument which is placed over a QtGui.QVBoxLayout. Though QTextEdit takes HTML input, but the "href" of anchor tag does no help to create a hyperlink inside the test of QTextEdit. Any idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should really be using a [QTextBrowser](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html) rather than a QTextEdit. The QTextBrowser class inherits QTextEdit, and is designed for viewing, and interacting with, read-only HTML documents.

By default, QTextBrowser will only attempt to open local links. If you also want open internet links, then do this:

```
textbrowser = QTextBrowser()
textbrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

This will open external links using the system default browser.